# Error in building new Universal App in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

am creating new application in Windows 10.

It is universal app. Whenever I try to run it I am getting error of SHEException

If I press on continue I get

[image]
I don't know what is problem. I recently installed windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015.

It was working fine few days ago.

It also works fine if build platform is changed to x64.

Problem seems to be with x86 only. an that too in debug mode. It works fine in release mode.

build log

1>------ Deploy started: Project: App2, Configuration: Debug x86 ------

1>Updating the layout...

1>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...

1>Warning : DEP0810 : This app references Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug, version 14.0.22929.0, found in your SDK, but you have a higher version of Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug installed on the target machine, 14.0.23019.0. If you continue to run this application, it will run against the currently installed version, Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug, version 14.0.23019.0. Consider updating your SDK to match the version of Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug that is installed.

1>Registering the application to run from layout...

1>Deployment complete (3093ms). Full package name: "e3539dd6-9c0d-484d-9539-dd8b1349d19a_1.0.0.0_x86__1fp2271dgb6y

Please suggest any solution
[image]

Comment: In my case it has happened with the Microsoft Advertising SDK and just in Debug - ARM, no idea how to solve

Comment: I uninstalled the app from the phone and it worked

Comment: I was having a similar issue. A trace with Procmon shows that it is a permissions failure(ACCESS_DENIED). While searching for a solution for a different issue I was able to fix it incidentally. I had to take ownership of a registry key. But I don't remember exactly which one it was. I was searching for how to change the default Install location for Modern Apps. I will try to find it again and post it if I do.